# How to find a user in B2C by ProxyAddresses?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to register a user in azure B2C, but I can't because another object with the property ProxyAddresses already exists. The problem is that when I try to find this user, it does not exist. Is there a way to find out which user is assigned whit this ProxyAddresses?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a user in B2C by **proxyAddresses**, you can make use of below Microsoft Graph API call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x+eq+'SMTP:{email}')
```

In my case, I ran below query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by signing in with B2C user consenting **`User.Read.All`** permission and got **response** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x+eq+'SMTP:sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com')&$select=id,displayName,proxyAddresses
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can get the **same results** by running below MS Graph PowerShell commands:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "User.Read.All"

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Users
Get-MgBetaUser -Filter  "proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'SMTP:sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com')" -Property "id,displayName,proxyAddresses"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Additionally, is there a way to remove only proxy addresses from users?

Comment: Could you post a new question with more details on your requirement?